# Access GWT functions from Flex widget

Tags: java, javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3, gwt

I want to develop a GWT javascript application that must interact with a flex widget and fire events from 2 directions (flex to GWT and GWT to flex)
For example I develop a function in GWT called `onWidgetSelected(int widgetID){ ...}` the generated javascript code does not contain the name of this function. So If I want to invoke it from flex through javascript call what should I do ?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a framework for facilitating communication between GWT-module and the "outside". You can use gwt-exporter for creating objects from outside and using them, or better, I'm building a small project for oferring gwt-objects as clean javascript objects (supporting translation of arguments). Check http://code.google.com/p/gwt-remote to see if it useful.

Comment: It's Ok I used gwt-flex library it works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cwallenpoole correctly showed you how to call JS from Flex. But since GWT produces obfuscated JS, you will not be able to call GWT Java methods by their native names.

In order to make this work, you will need to "export" the method as described here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to talk about JS and AS talking to each other, you need to think about the [EnternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class in Flash. In this case, it sounds like you want to call [addCallBack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) and call

```
EnternalInterface.addCallBack("onWidgetSelected",onWidgetSelected);
```

In JS:

```
document.getElementById("#swf-id").onWidgetSelected( 1 );
```

And to call JS from AS:

```
EnternalInterface.call("alert",1);
```

Comment: Yes I have read this .. but the problem is that the GWT does not generate a function called onWidgetSelected. It generates a non understandable code

Comment: Where are you developing this function?

Comment: I want to develop it in GWT which generates at the end an unreadable code. I can't invoke js GWT function because I don't know how to ?